# Вопрос про массив в php

Tags: php

Есть php массив или объект, структура которого заранее не известна, как сохранить данные из него в файл для последующего использования в таком же виде (в виде такого же массив или объекта)?

Comment: `$data = json_encode($array); file_put_contents($file, $data, LOCK_EX);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете использовать для этого функции https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php и https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

```
$some_array_or_plain_object = []; //new Stdclass;
file_put_contents('file.txt', serialize($some_array_or_plain_object));
var_dump(unserialize(file_get_contents('file.txt')));
```

Либо (что предпочтительнее):
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

```
$some_array_or_plain_object = []; //new Stdclass;
file_put_contents('file.txt', json_encode($some_array_or_plain_object));
var_dump(json_decode(file_get_contents('file.txt'), true)); //получите массив
var_dump(json_decode(file_get_contents('file.txt'))); //получите объект
```